# Map of number of occurrences in a list

Tags: haskell, substring, find-occurrences

I'm working with this type of list:

`data Elem = Dot | Star`

and I've to print a list of tuples, with 2 units, in which the first indicates the length of a sequence of "Star" in the list and the second lists the locations where this sequence appears (the first position is 1). Possibly without using built in function.

The function is:

`occ :: [Elem] -> [(Int, [Int])]`

EDIT:
My idea is: split the problem in two functions, one for find the position of every "Star", one for lists the locations.

EDIT2:
Example:

`occ [Dot,Star,Dot,Star,Dot,Star,Star,Star]`

`[(1,[2,4]), (3,[6])]`

EDIT3:
http://pastebin.com/uvvXBARL

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your problem, shouldn't the type of occ be [Elem] -> (Int, [Int])? There is no reason that it should output a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for complexity, but this work:

```
import Data.List
data Elem = Dot | Star
occ :: [Elem] -> [(Int, [Int])]
occ list = reduce (occ_hlp list 1 0 0 [])

-- Help function, which find all subsequence of Stars
occ_hlp [] pos cur_pos cur_len result       | cur_len == 0 = result
                                            | otherwise = ((cur_len, [cur_pos]):result)
occ_hlp (Star:t) pos cur_pos cur_len result | cur_len == 0 = occ_hlp t (pos + 1) pos 1 result
                                            | otherwise = occ_hlp t (pos + 1) cur_pos (cur_len + 1) result
occ_hlp (Dot:t) pos cur_pos cur_len result  | pos == 1 = occ_hlp t (pos + 1) 0 0 result
                                            | otherwise = occ_hlp t (pos + 1) 0 0 ((cur_len, [cur_pos]) : result)

-- Reduce obtained subsequence of Stars with same length                                            
reduce list = filter (\x -> not $ (snd x) == []) 
                 $ [(elem, sort $ foldl (\x y -> x ++ (snd y)) [] (filter (\x -> (fst x) == elem) list)) | elem <- [1..max_len]] 
                     where max_len = maximum $ map (fst) list
```

In this program i have 2 help functions:

1) occ_help, which find all [(Int, [Int])] subsequence of Stars.
For your example:

```
occ_hlp [Dot,Star,Dot,Star,Dot,Star,Star,Star] 1 0 0 []
```

will returns list of subsequence:

```
[(3,[6]),(1,[4]),(1,[2])]
```

2) reduce, which folds list of these elements to required list
Example:

```
reduce [(3,[6]),(1,[4]),(1,[2])]
```

will returns your result:

```
[(1,[2,4]),(3,[6])]
```